# Error message - 'No value given for one or more required parameters'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

***RESOLVED***

I am having a bit of trouble with querying an Access database in VB.NET and was hoping someone would be able to help.

When I enter into the TextBox it is supposed to show users that contain the inputted letters in their name.

There are no errors coming up in the code itself but there is an error message ('No value given for one or more required parameters') when I enter into the TextBox and click the button that is supposed to search the database for that surname and display the selected details of that customer only.

There are two pages of code, the first is a **Control Class** and the second is the code for the **Query Form Code**.

**Control Class:**

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DBControl
    'CREATE YOUR DB CONNECTION
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=Hotel.mdb;")
    'PREPARE DB COMMAND
    Private DBCmd As OleDbCommand

    'DB DATA
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    'QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    'QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        'RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            'OPEN A CONNECTION
            DBCon.Open()

            'CREATE DB COMMAND
            DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

            'LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            'CLEAR PARAMS LIST
            Params.Clear()

            'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATABASE
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = ex.Message
        End Try

        'CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    'INCLUDE QUERY & COMMAND PARAMETERS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Query Form Code:**

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class RoomQuery
    Private Access As New DBControl

    Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    End Function

    Private Sub Query_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'RUN QUERY
        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Surname ASC")
        If NotEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

        'FILL DATAGRID
        dgvCustomers.DataSource = Access.DBDT

        'FILL COMBOBOX
        For Each R As DataRow In Access.DBDT.Rows
            cbxCustomers.Items.Add(R("Surname"))
        Next

        'DISPLAY FIRS NAME FOUND
        If Access.RecordCount > 0 Then cbxCustomers.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchCustomers(Surname As String)
        'ADD PARAMETERS & RUN QUERY
        Access.AddParam("@Surname", "%" & Surname & "%")
        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT Forename, Surname, Number, Email, City/County FROM Customers " &
                         "WHERE Surname LIKE @Surname")

        'REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
        If NotEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

        'FILL COMBOBOX
        dgvCustomers.DataSource = Access.DBDT
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        SearchCustomers(txtSearch.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for your time and I look forward to any responses provided  :)

***Edit on the Query Form Code:***

```vb
Public Class RoomQuery
    Private Access As New DBControl

    Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    End Function

    Private Sub Query_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'RUN QUERY
        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Surname ASC")
        If NotEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

        'FILL DATAGRID
        dgvCustomers.DataSource = Access.DBDT

        'FILL COMBOBOX
        For Each R As DataRow In Access.DBDT.Rows
            cbxCustomers.Items.Add(R("Surname"))
        Next

        'DISPLAY FIRS NAME FOUND
        If Access.RecordCount > 0 Then cbxCustomers.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchCustomers(Surname As String)
        'ADD PARAMETERS & RUN QUERY
        Access.AddParam("@Surname", "%" & Surname & "%")
        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT Title, Forename,  Surname, Number, Email, City FROM Customers WHERE Surname LIKE @Surname")

        'REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
        If NotEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

        'FILL COMBOBOX
        dgvCustomers.DataSource = Access.DBDT
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        SearchCustomers(txtSearch.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works now - thank you all for your comments :)

Comment: `City/County` means "divide column City by column County". I assume that's not what you're doing, and you have a column named `City/County` instead, in which case it should be bracketed.

Comment: `City/County`? Is that the name of a Field? -- Are you sure that  `Access.AddParam(("@Surname", "%" & Surname & "%")` in `"WHERE Surname LIKE @Surname")` can work like that? It's usually `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField LIKE '%' + @Parameter + '%'"`

Comment: Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention. Nor reserved words as names. Otherwise, have to enclose in brackets. Access queries use `*` wildcard by default, not `%`.

Comment: "When I try to use the ComboBox nothing happens" What combo box? I don't see any events for a combo box.

Comment: Did you write this code, yourself? It is okay if you didn't but I wonder if you understand it.

Comment: @Mary I watched a video that my teacher recommended and said that works (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q19OXha1jDw&t=1966s). It does work now that I have changed the field name in Access from "City/County" to just "City". As for the ComboBox: after watching it again I realised that it isn't supposed to filter, just fill up with the chosen field (I did wonder why it only has the code for the DataGridView (dgvCustomers.DataSource = Access.DBDT)).